# Upgrade from Netbeans 7.2.1 to Netbeans 7.3.1 classpath error

Tags: java, gwt, netbeans-7, glassfish-4

I recently upgraded from Netbeans 7.2.1 to Netbeans 7.3.1. I have an existing GWT project using JDK 7 EE. Upon setting up Netbeans 7.3.1 to point to Glassfish 4 and redeploying to the new server, I see this warning in the output window of Netbeans:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
```

What is this warning and should I be concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into my GWT project properties and found a drop-down that was pointing to JDK 6. I changed it to JDK 7 and the warning went away.